# What does "The results speak for themselves" mean?

Tags: meaning

> The late Sam Schlosser, the S of F & S, had praised Mr. Martin at a staff meeting several years before for his temperate habits. "Our most efficient worker neither drinks nor smokes," he had said. "*The results speak for themselves*."

What does *The results speak for themselves* mean? Could you paraphrase it please?

Answer (score 3):

It means, literally, that the results do not have to be "interpreted" because their significance is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

When a task has been completed successfully without any errors, there is no need to worry about the outcome of it. Once people start using that, they would appreciate the splendid effort. So this is an simple example where results will automatically speak.